# Why is the dimension of $SL(2,\mathbb{H})$ equal to $15$?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, quaternions

Let me ask a very basic question which is inspired by reading M. Atiyah's "Geometry and physics of knots". Could you explain me (or give a reference to) the definition of the special linear group $SL(2,\mathbb{H})$?

What I don't understand is how to compute the determinant of a matrix with noncommutative entries. Further, even if there was some way to define it, the naive counting gives $12$ for the dimension of $SL(2,\mathbb{H})$, whereas it is clear from the context that it should be equal to $15$.

To solve the contradiction I thought that, probably, $SL(2,\mathbb{H})$ is not defined as a matrix group with determinant equal to $1$, but rather as a group of fractional linear transformations of $\mathbb{HP}^1$. Could someone please confirm if this is correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a notion of a determinant for matrices with coefficients in a noncommutative ring due to Dieudonné. Also the quaternions can be seen as a subring of $M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb C)$, so that $M_{2\times 2}(\Bbb H)\subset M_{4\times 4}(\Bbb C)$ as a subring. That gives you at least one possible definition of a $\Bbb C$-valued determinant. You could search "quaternionic determinant" on google, and "Dieudonné determinant". As for dimension, I would expect that the above determinant is a submersion onto $\Bbb C^*$ so that $SL(2,\Bbb H)$ should have complex dimension 15.

Comment: The dimesion statement in my comment is false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Lie algebra $sl_2(\mathbb H)$ is easier to define: it's the Lie algebra *generated* by traceless matrices. In non-commutative case the space of traceless matrices is not closed under Lie bracket — that's why dim>12. In fact, $sl_2(\mathbb H)$ is the Lie algebra of matrices with pure imaginary trace.
2. $SL(2,\mathbb R)\cong Spin(2,1)$, $SL(2,\mathbb C)\cong Spin(3,1)$. Now $Spin(5,1)$ is connected and 1-connected, has Lie algebra $sl_2(\mathbb H)$ (and acts by conformal transformations on $\mathbb HP^1$, btw) — so $SL(2,\mathbb H)\cong Spin(5,1)$ (and is 15-dimensional). (All this is explained somewhere in Baez's [Octonions](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/octonions.html), I believe.)
3. *It seems* (after googling) that $SL_2(\mathbb H)$ can also be defined as the commutator subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb H)$ and this is exactly the subgroup of matrices with Dieudonné determinant equal to 1.

Comment: (and the group of fractional transformations is usually not SL but PSL — i.e. slightly smaller)

Comment: In "1," how can an algebra generated by traceless matrices also be an algebra of matrices with pure imaginary trace (in particular, how could it not contain the traceless matrices that generated it)?

Comment: @j0equ1nn 0 *is* a pure imaginary number